# Determining what language a string contains in a pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, textblob

I am new to Pandas and Python.

My dataframe:

**df**

```
Text
Best tv in 2020
utilizar un servicio sms gratuito
utiliser un tv pour netflix
```

**My desired output**

```
Text                                    Language
Best tv in 2020                         en
utilizar un servicio sms gratuito       es
utiliser un tv pour netflix             fr
```

**What I am using:**

```
from textblob import TextBlob

b = TextBlob("utilizar un servicio sms gratuito")
print(b.detect_language())

>>es
```

I am not sure how I could integrate this method to fill my Pandas Dataframe.

**I have tried:**

```
df['Language'] = TextBlob(df['Text']).detect_language()
```

But I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: The `text` argument passed to `__init__(text)` must be a string, not <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I understand what it means, that I need to pass a string rather than pandas DataFrame Series, so my question is how would I loop the entire Series to detect language per row in column `text`?

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with lambda function:

```
df['Language'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: TextBlob(x).detect_language())
```

Or [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['Language'] = df['Text'].map(lambda x: TextBlob(x).detect_language())
```

---

```
print (df)
                                Text Language
0                    Best tv in 2020       en
1  utilizar un servicio sms gratuito       es
2        utiliser un tv pour netflix       fr
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael and thank you as always. Any comments on the performance difference between these two solutions?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - First is more common for pass functions, but not working for index values, second is used for `df.index.map`, also working  for columns like in answer.

Comment: understood, thanks. Not sure if you have worked with textblob before, but now I am getting `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 429: Too Many Requests`, any idea for workarounds?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis - I working with it first time, but I guess there is some protection for avoid many requests...