# How to detect the language of a sentence in python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

I am trying to detect the language of a sentence in python. I tried 'langdetect' and 'nltk word corpus' but nothing is giving the expected results:
My example df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['Auxiliar Director/a de Hotel', 'Jefe de Tienda', 'Data Analyst']})
```

and expected result is:

```
    text                            detected_language
0   Auxiliar Director/a de Hotel    spanish
1   Jefe de Tienda                  spanish
2   Data Analyst                    english
```

TIA!

Comment: [Determining what language a string contains in a pandas DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59610076/15497888), [Python: How to determine the language?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39142778/15497888)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is for 'langdetect' to work, it requires **large portions of text**. When I extend your word phrases, it detected the language correctly.

Extended phrases

- 'La subdirectora del hotel es muy buena, me gusta.'
- "El gerente de latienda es un papel clave en este complejo comercial."
- 'Data Analyst is a great job'

Code used to predict

```py
from langdetect import detect, DetectorFactory
#pip install iso-639
from iso639 import languages

DetectorFactory.seed = 0
out = detect('El gerente de la tienda es un papel clave en este complejo comercial.')
out_full = languages.get(alpha2=out).name
print(out_full)
```

Output

```
Spanish
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the ans but my sentences are that long only. What if I only want to derect whether a sentence is in English or not. And return true and false. Any pointers on that?